# Negative binomial distribution for bounded data

Tags: regression, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution

Why is the negbin distribution required when the analyzed count data is bounded? I don't really understand the following:

> "The Poisson distribution can form the
>   basis for some analyses of count data
>   and in this case Poisson regression
>   may be used. This is a special case of
>   the class of generalized linear models
>   which also contains specific forms of
>   model capable of using the binomial
>   distribution (binomial regression,
>   logistic regression) or the negative
>   binomial distribution where the
>   assumptions of the Poisson model are
>   violated, in particular when the range
>   of count values is limited or when
>   overdispersion is present." ---
>   [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_data)

Comment: Neither "limited" nor "overdispersion" imply "bounded."  The Wikipedia article on [overdispersion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdispersion) points out that the negative binomial is a gamma mixture of Poissons, allowing it to handle overdispersion.  The article you cite is in a nascent phase; it uses "limited" only in a vague colloquial way that one hopes will be improved as the article evolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Poisson distribution, the variance is equal to the mean. 
The negative binomial distribution has a variance that is greater than the mean by some factor -- hence it's "overdispersed" relative to the Poisson.

In marketing theory (see Ehrenberg's Repeat Buying), purchases by a given individual have a Poisson distribution, with individual lambdas.  But since your lambda and my lambda are different values, the overall variance is higher.  In a negative binomial, the lambdas are assumed to follow a gamma distribution.

Comment: Hey! Could you give me the page where it's been said, that the poisson-gamma mixture model include that there are different means, or lambdas, for the individuals? Thank you for your answer, it sounds interesting!

Comment: Schmittlein et al. is one http://www.essec.edu/faculty/showDeclFileRes.do?declId=355&key=Publication-Content   (see first paragraph).  This will lead back eventually to Ehrenberg, Repeat Buying, section 7.2 (compound Poisson model). http://www.marketplanet.ru/filestore/0041/0037/939/repeat_buying.pdf